# Accessing Microsoft Cognitive Service through Restful Service

Tags: c#, rest, azure-cognitive-services

I'm receiving the following error while accessing the Microsoft Cognitive API:

[image]

I'm 100% sure that my subscription key is valid because I have tested it in DHC as well as the online tool of Project Oxford.

I'm using sample code provided by Microsoft. Here it is...

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("safeee");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{bce8988422e94fd3ac64xxxxxxxxxxxx}");

var uri = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/persongroups/{personGroupId}?" + queryString;

HttpResponseMessage response;

byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{body}");

using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);

    MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Should your key be inside braces `{}`? The other samples I've seen don't have the key inside braces.

Comment: Did you try creating a new subscription key using a different account? If there is some problem with your account it needs to be checked with Microsoft Support.

Comment: @Equalsk I have tried without braces. Then it gives the error of "Bad Request"

Comment: @SouvikGhosh. I'm not convinced to generate new subscription key or validate it with difference account because this subscription key is working with DHC and https://dev.projectoxford.ai/

Comment: To me it sounds like a `Bad Request` is actually progress. Previously you were failing authentication so it didn't even evaluate your query and gave you the access denied error. Now you're authenticated it evaluates your query, finds something wrong and gives you this error. What's the message along with bad request?

Comment: Actually it is giving me the same error even without braces.. :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your original error was "401 Access Denied". You said the new error without braces was "Bad Request". Which one are you getting and what is the whole error?

Comment: Error Without Braces:

{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  apim-request-id: 83d65d82-663c-4900-b3fb-ee982380e48f
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2016 16:16:14 GMT
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 72
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}

Comment: @Equalsk Please help

Answer (score 0):

For any code snippet in the Microsoft Cognitive Services site, including the [page](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395244) to which I believe you're referring, you need to substitute all curly-braced strings with appropriate values.  In your case, you need to:

1. Drop the query string `"safeee"` from the `queryString`.  There are no query parameters for this particular endpoint.
2. Drop the curly braces in the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` value (sounds like you tried that.)
3. Give an approriate `personGroupId` value.  Per the documentation on the aforementioned page, "valid characters include numbers, English letters in lower case, '-' and '_'. The maximum length of the personGroupId is 64."
4. Provide a proper JSON value for `body`.  In your case you might simply use `"{\"name\":\"safeee\"}"`.